# Get position of click on image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to be able to get the position of a click in an image. I would like to get the coordinates on the image itself and not in the container of the page.

The closest I have arrived is this:

```
<template>
  <div class="image-annotation">
    <div style="position: relative">
      <!-- image-annotation__marker class has styles to center place the pointer in a absolute positioning -->
      <div class="image-annotation__marker" :style="markerStyle" />
      <img
          ref="image"
          src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/HlgucZ0ylJAfZgusynnUwxNIgIp5htNhShF559x3dRXiuy_UdP3UQVLYW6c=s1200"
          alt="Art image"
          @click="onClickImage"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class Counter extends Vue {
  public activeCoordinates: { x: number; y: number } | null = null;
  
  public $refs!: {
    image: HTMLElement
  }

  get hideSecondColumn() {
    return this.activeCoordinates !== null
  }

  get markerStyle() {
    if (this.activeCoordinates === null) return { display: 'none' }

    return {
      top: `${this.activeCoordinates.y}px`,
      left: `${this.activeCoordinates.x}px`,
    }
  }

  public onClickImage(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.activeCoordinates = {
      x: event.pageX - this.$refs.image.offsetTop,
      y: event.pageY - this.$refs.image.offsetLeft,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But when click on the image I get the following point in the image (the point is not exactly where I clicked)

[image: point position upon click]

I would like to get the point exactly where I clicked on the image

Comment: and where did you click?

Comment: I clicked to the left side of it. I tried to include the cursor on the image but couldn't take a screenshot and include the cursor at the same time. I solved the issue by replacing `event.pageX - this.$refs.image.offsetTop` to `event.offsetX`. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It would help others in the future to post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was a very simple solution. Replace `event.pageX - this.$refs.image.offsetTop` to `event.offsetX`.

From MDN docs:

> The offsetX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

vs

> The pageX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface returns the X (horizontal) coordinate (in pixels) at which the mouse was clicked, relative to the left edge of the entire document. This includes any portion of the document not currently visible.